SRF calculation of a capacitor with trace inductance
I've been reading a Texas Instruments guide on decoupling of Operational Amplifiers (freely available here). On page 10, an example is given on how even a 1.5 cm circuit trace changes the overall inductance so that the SRF drops from 1.92 GHz to only 314 MHz. While I can easily calculate the 1.92 GHz from the well-known formula given on page 2, I don't know how he arrived at this extreme drop. If I add the inductances, I get 1.62 GHz. Can anyone spot the mistake? Thanks!

Show your work. Exactly what formula did you use? If I use the usual formula for resonant frequency I get 1.99 GHz for 27.77 pF and 0.23 nH; and I get 314.4 MHz for 27.77 pF and 9.23 nH.

Resonant frequency is $$f_\mathrm{res}=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}.$$
Given C = 27.77 pF and L = 0.23 nH from the document, \$f_\mathrm{res}=1.99\ \mathrm{GHz}\$. Adding the additional 9 nH to L gives C = 27.77 pF and L = 9.23 nH, which in the same formula produces \$f_\mathrm{res}=314.4\ \mathrm{MHz}\$.
This agrees with the document's claims.
I'm not sure how you get 1.92 GHz or 1.62 GHz, really--you'd have to show your work for me to identify the specific mistake made.

You have to use the value of 30 pF, the 27.77 pF are only a parasitic capacitance. I somehow managed to have a typo in my calculation of L. With the 0.23 nH, I get the desired result. Thanks!
